# How to parse key/value chain into associative array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a string that looks like: `key1/value1/key2/value2/` and so on

I did an `explode('/',trim($mystring,'/'))` on that

Now I want to haven an associative array like:

```
array(
 'key1' => 'value1',
 'key2' => 'value2',
  ...
);
```

of course i can do it with an for loop where i always read two entries and push them into a target array, but isnt there something more efficient and elegant? a one liner with some some php core function similar to ·list()· or something?

Comment: Most probably not. But you can define your own function and reuse it, then you have your one liner ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A method using array_walk() with a callback function:

```
function buildNewArray($value, $key, &$newArray) {
    (($key % 2) == 0) ? $newArray[$value] = '' : $newArray[end(array_keys($newArray))] = $value;
}

$myString = 'key1/value1/key2/value2/';
$myArray = explode('/',trim($myString,'/'));

$newArray = array();
array_walk($myArray, 'buildNewArray', &$newArray);

var_dump($newArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

If the format is not changin (i mean it is allways *Key1/value1/key2/value2*) it should be easy.

After the explode you have this:

```
$arr = Array('key1','value1','key2','value2')
```

so you now can do:

```
$new_arr = array();
$i = 0;    
for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i+=2)
{
   $new_arr[$arr[i]] = $arr[$i+1];
}
```

at the end of the loop you will have:

```
$new_arr = array("key1"=>"value1","key2"=>"value2")
```

KISS :)

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

One can **always** make yourself a one liner.

This is called **[User-defined functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php)**

No need to devise something ugly-but-one-liner-at-any-cost.
Make your own function and you will get much shorter, cleaner and way more reliable result.
A function, which will not only do elementary string operations but also do something more intelligent, like parameter validation.